# Necessary condition for local existence of solution for system of two first order PDEs

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, vector-fields

> Let $f,g$ be two smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $U,V$ be two smooth vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$. What is the sufficient condition for local existence of a solution $\phi$ of equations
>   \begin{align}
> U \cdot \nabla \phi &= f \\
> V \cdot \nabla \phi &=g
> \end{align}

I know the answer if $U=(1,0)$ and $V=(0,1)$. Then we have classical problem of finding potential for vector field $(f,g)$ and the sufficient condition for local existence is that curl of $(f,g)$ has to be zero. In the virtue of this classical problem, we can try to derive similar condition
\begin{align}
(V\cdot \nabla)(U\cdot \nabla)\phi &= (V\cdot\nabla)f \\
(U\cdot \nabla)(v\cdot \nabla)\phi &= (U\cdot\nabla)g \\
\end{align}
Using comutator $[A,B] = AB-BA$ we can rewrite the first equation as
\begin{align}
(U\cdot \nabla)(V\cdot \nabla)\phi + [(V\cdot \nabla),(U\cdot \nabla)] \phi &= (V\cdot\nabla)f
\end{align}
This leads to 
\begin{align}
 [(V\cdot \nabla),(U\cdot \nabla)] \phi = (V\cdot\nabla)f - (U\cdot\nabla)g
\end{align}
If the commutator vanishes then the condition is
\begin{align}
 0 = (V\cdot\nabla)f - (U\cdot\nabla)g
\end{align}
Which, I think, can be proven to be a sufficient condition for local existence. But what happens when the commutator does not vanish?

---

The problem can be reformulated in the language of differential geometry

> Let $X,Y$ be two vector fields on manifold $M$. What is the necessary condition for local existence of a function $\phi$ which satisfy
>   \begin{align}
> X(\phi) &= 1 \\
> Y(\phi) &= 1
> \end{align}

Connection to the previous formulation is
\begin{align}
X &= \frac{U}{f} \cdot \nabla \\
Y &= \frac{V}{g} \cdot \nabla
\end{align}

If $[X,Y] = 0$ then I can find coordinate functions $\psi_x$ and $\psi_y$ such that 
\begin{align}
X(\psi_x) &= 1\\
X(\psi_y) &= 0\\
Y(\psi_x) &= 0\\
Y(\psi_y) &= 1
\end{align}
Then the solution is $\phi = \psi_x + \psi_y$.

If $[X,Y] \neq 0$, I cannot solve the problem with coordinate functions, but can I find $\phi$? Or I'm guaranteed that it does not exists?